# $.params vs JSON.stringify on Rails ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

When trying to make an AJAX call to Rails, I have some question about `JSON.stringify()` and `$.param`
This code work

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/api/v1/login',
  dataType: 'application/json',
  method: 'post',
  data: $.param({"user": attrs}),
  success: function(a,b,c) {
    alert(JSON.parse(b));
  }
});
```

This code doesn't

```
  $.ajax({
    url: '/api/v1/login',
    dataType: 'application/json',
    method: 'post',
    data: $.JSON.stringify({"user": attrs}),
    success: function(a,b,c) {
      alert(JSON.parse(b));
    }
  });
```

`$.param({"user": attrs})` returns `user%5Busername%5D=ABC&user%5Bpassword%5D=123456`
`JSON.stringify({"user": attrs})` returns `{"user":{"username":"triet","password":"123456"}}`

I think `JSON.stringify` should work, but when I consult the rails console, it gives me `{"{\"user\":{\"username\":\"triet\",\"password\":\"123456\"}}"=>"[FILTERED]"}`.

Could anyone tell me why there is a [FILTERED] part? I couldn't find any doc mentions about it. Thank you

Comment: what is the overall issue that doesn't let you pass your object without using `$.param` or `JSON.stringify` ?

Comment: `data: $.param({"user": attrs})` pretty cool, didn't know you can do that. @charlietfl - this is useful in Rails, where attributes can only be mass-assigned if they are namespaced with the object name.

Comment: @maxpleaner jQuery will parse the data internally for you, no need for it in this instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `data` option takes a string only as a serialized representation i.e. `user%5Busername%5D=ABC&user%5Bpassword%5D=123456`.

So there is a wrong format of `data` if you set it to `$.JSON.stringify({"user": attrs})` i.e. `"{\"user\":{\"username\":\"triet\",\"password\":\"123456\"}}"`.

If you need to send JSON data so you should use it without `JSON.stringify` as `Object` like that:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/api/v1/login',
  dataType: 'application/json',
  method: 'post',
  data: {"user": attrs},
  success: function(a,b,c) {
    alert(JSON.parse(b));
  }
});
```

And this request should work.

So I don't think that the problem was in `[FILTERED]` because this is just Rails filters secure values **only** from logs. The data weren't touched.

Comment: Your code works, thank you. What is your advice when `data` is not that simple, should I use `$.param`?

Comment: _So I don't think that the problem was in [FILTERED] because this is just Rails filters secure values only from logs. The data weren't touched._ I mean the `[FILTERED]` at the last of the JSON, not the one automatically filtered out when Rails receives a password.

Comment: *What is your advice when data is not that simple, should I use $.param?* - if your data is an `Object` the `ajax` converts it to a appropriate param string by itself. So you can set `data` to your `Object` almost always as is. In my practive I never use `$.param` before.

Comment: *I mean the [FILTERED] at the last of the JSON, not the one automatically filtered out when Rails receives a password.* - In my opinion: because of your `data` was of incorrect format, `$.ajax` method threats it as a key name of a param and value of this key is `null`. Rails sees that key contains "password" string and thinks that its value is secure and filters it. You can use Firebug (or whateverelse) to see what request is sent by `$.ajax` method, I sure that my guess is right and there is a param with `"{\"user\":{\"username\":\"triet\",\"password\":\"123456\"}}"` key and `null` value.